# Authenticating with x11vnc: what's the difference between -auth and -rfbauth?

Tags: authentication, remote, vnc, x-server

I'm on xubuntu 11.10 trying to setup x11vnc server.

I followed instructions [here](http://mlepicki.com/?p=10) and I can connect to VNC server - but it never asks me for password!

Is there a difference between these 2 options:

```
-auth file
and
-rfbauth passwd-file
```

Or why wouldn't my VNC client (remmina) ask for password. any clues?

**UPDATE:**
OK. - I've added **-rfbauth** option and now authentication works with that single password.

I can connect and prompted for password:

```
x11vnc -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -display :0 \
-auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -forever -bg -o /var/log/x11vnc.log \
-rfbauth /etc/.x11vnc.pass
```

I can connect but NOT! prompted for password:

```
x11vnc -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -display :0 \
-auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -forever -bg -o /var/log/x11vnc.log
```

I don't get - what is the reason for -auth option then if not for authentication?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`x11vnc -auth $XAUTHORITY` starts a VNC server where you authenticate with an X [cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xauth#Cookie-based_access). A cookie is a byte sequence that is randomly generated when the X server starts and which (under most setups nowadays) any application that wants to connect to the X server must provide. The cookie is typically stored in a file called `~/.Xauthority` or indicated by the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable. You can manipulate cookie files with the `xauth` command. You would not normally type X cookies manually; rather, you'd copy them with judicious use of `cp` (and commands such as ssh may copy them automatically). A common use case is `x11vnc -auth guess`, which says to use the same cookie when going through the x11vnc channel as when connecting to the X server directly.

`x11vnc -rfbauth $RFB_PASSWORD_FILE` starts a VNC server where you authenticate by typing a password. If you don't specify `-rfbauth`, anyone can connect to the VNC server (but not then connect to the X server unless they know the X cookie or your X server accepts connections without a cookie).